# Error 91 in VBA using classes

Tags: class, vba

I'm currently trying to implement a Clark & Wright Savings Heurisitc in VBA, but I'm currently facing some problem. I'm fairly new to VBA, and this error (91) keeps apearing on similar situations, which lead me to believe I'm missing some crucial knowledge. Next I present you the code:

```
    Public Sub CWsavings()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim aux As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim r As Integer


Dim Cu(200) As customer
Dim De(12) As Depot

For i = 1 To 200

    Set Cu(i) = New customer

    Cu(i).custID = i
     Cu(i).longitude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 2)
     Cu(i).latitude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 3)
     Cu(i).lt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 4)
     Cu(i).et = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 5)
     Cu(i).weekdemand = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 6)
     Cu(i).peakdemand = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 7)
     Cu(i).D1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 8)
     Cu(i).D2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 9)
    Next i

For j = 1 To 12

    Set De(j) = New Depot

    De(j).depotID = j
    De(j).Dname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 13)
    De(j).latitude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 14)
    De(j).longitude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Folha1").Cells(i + 1, 15)
    De(j).ncust = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(j, 7)
    De(j).nroute = 0

    For k = 1 To De(j).ncust
        aux = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(j + 1, 10 + k)
       Call De(j).SetCustomer(Cu(aux), k)                              
    Next k

Next j

For d = 1 To 12


    Dim M(30, 30) As Double
    Dim maxsav As Double
    Dim maxpos(2) As Integer
    Dim connorder(676, 2) 'order of connections for routing
    Dim it As Integer

    it = 0

For i = 1 To De(d).ncust
    For j = 1 To De(d).ncust
      M(i, j) = CalcSavings(De(d), De(d).customer(i), De(d).customer(j))   ' error here
    Next j
Next i

itbegin:

    maxsav = 0
    maxpos(1) = 0
    maxpos(2) = 0


    For i = 1 To De(d).ncust
        For j = 1 To De(d).ncust
            If i <> j Then
                If M(i, j) > maxsav Then
                    maxsav = M(i, j)
                    maxpos(1) = i
                    maxpos(j) = j
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    it = it + 1

    connorder(it, 1) = maxpos(1)
    connorder(it, 2) = maxpos(2)

    If it < De(d).ncust * De(d).ncust - ncust Then
        M(maxpos(1), maxpos(2)) = 0

        GoTo itbegin
    End If
Next d

End Sub

Public Function CalcSavings(d As Depot, C1 As customer, C2 As customer)

Dim id As Double
Dim dj As Double
Dim ij As Double

id = DeptDist(C1, d)
dj = DeptDist(C2, d)
ij = CustDist(C1, C2)

CalcSavings = id + dj - ij

End Function
```

The class Depot:

```
        Public depotID As Integer
Public Dname As String
Public latitude As Double
Public longitude As Double
Private customers(200) As customer
Public ncust As Integer
Private routes(500) As route
Public nroute As Integer

Public Sub addcust(C As customer)

    ncust = ncust + 1
    Set customers(ncust) = C

End Sub

Public Sub addroute(R As route)

    nroute = Me.nroute + 1
    Set routes(Me.nroute) = R

End Sub

Public Property Get customer(i As Integer) As customer

    customer = customers(i)

End Property

Public Sub SetCustomer(C As customer, i As Integer)

   Set customers(i) = C

End Sub

Public Property Get route(i As Integer) As route

    route = routes(i)

End Property

Public Sub SetRoute(R As route, i As Integer)

   Set routes(i) = R

End Sub
```

(Class depot Updated)

And the class Customer:

```
Public custID As Integer
Public latitude As Double
Public longitude As Double
Public lt As Double
Public et As Double
Public weekdemand As Integer
Public peakdemand As Integer
Public D1 As Integer
Public D2 As Integer
```

I'm sorry for the long post, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any pointers on the line at which the error occurs? One thing that jumps to mind while looking at your code, is that you start your array indexes at 1, whereas by default they start at 0 in Excel. When declaring an array, the number inside parentheses isn't the size, it is the max index. For example `Dim cu(200) as customer` will declare an array with indexes going from 0-200 (size = 201)

Comment: Usually error 91 is related to objects not being well set, but your code seems ok. Only thing I see that could be causing the problem is those array indexes (since your arrays are dealing with objects).

Comment: @BernardSaucier, I'm aware that in vba arrays start with zero, I've been programming with that in mind. But if I code the loops to go from 1 to 200 (meaning ignoring the 0) there should be no problem right? What could be the problem  when dealing with arrays of objects, "callin" the wrong index and therefore the object being non-existant?

Comment: It's exactly why I'm not seeing anything wrong, but was pointing it out in case at some point you used the 0 index implicitly.

Comment: You mean clicking the debug and see whats's yellow? I've been doing that to check the indexes and they're correct. I don't know if there is some more advanced debugging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final answer...**

VERY ODDLY, (not that odd, when you really look at it, but) you need to use `Set` even in your `Get` properties. I guess the reason behind this is because you're returning an object, and even though that object may already exist, you're not going to use that very object. A copy is used instead and `Set` becomes vital to initialize that copy.

For example, here's what your "get customer" should look like :

```
Public Property Get customer(i As Integer) As customer

    Set customer = customers(i)

End Property
```

I guess it all makes sense; your array is private, and therefore you wouldn't want to pass the exact object that is contained inside that array, or it'd be counter-logic.

---

I think I found it... again...!

Try this :

```
Public Sub SetCustomer(C As customer, i As Integer)

   Set customers(i) = C

End Sub
```

Notice `customer(i)` was replaced by `customers(i)`

**EDIT :** Deleted previous answer, as I was mostly fishing.

Comment: Even if you were fishing I truly appreciate the help. Indeed it solved the first error (the one with the call). Thank you very much, There was another error, I'm not sure if you noticed, about the matrix M a bit down also with comment after, and that one still remains (same error code). I thought the error originated from the same source but apparently not.

Comment: But customers is not a property, customers() is a private array (I could not define it as public, I don't know why).

Comment: In this case, what are the values of d, i and j when the execution stops?